# Header Bidding In adserver

Tags: advertisement-server

I need to learn about header bidding in adserver, I have find below site `https://martechtoday.com/martech-landscape-what-is-header-bidding-and-why-should-publishers-care-157065` after reading this site also can't able to understand about header bidding, Can anyone suggest the best site to learn about header bidding

Answer (score 2):

Though this question is kind of dated, I thought it would still be a good idea to share some links:
YouTube - [header bidding 101](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tkxkBxe2wNw)
[The beginner's guide to header bidding](http://adprofs.co/beginners-guide-to-header-bidding/)
[image: How Header Bidding Works Diagram]
[Header Bidding framework](http://prebid.org/overview/intro.html)

Answer (score 0):

there are a few articles that may help you to understand header bidding and how it works with respect to an ad server:

1. https://headerbidding.co/header-bidding/ - This will help to understand what is header bidding and how it is different than the traditional waterfall method.
2. https://headerbidding.co/header-bidding-amp/ - This article has simplified the header bidding process for accelerated mobile pages.
3. https://headerbidding.co/prebid-setup-google-ad-manager/ - Google's ad server is one of the best ad servers for a publisher. And via Prebid, the open-source platform, you can easily get started with header bidding.
4. https://headerbidding.co/setup-exchange-bidding/- This article will help you understand how to enable open bidding in Google Ad Manager and why it is less efficient than client-side header bidding.

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions about header bidding.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)